# Checking if a ValidationGroup is valid from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, validation

Is there a method I can call that retrieves a boolean value of whether or not a particular ValidationGroup is valid?  **I don't want to actually display the validation message or summary** - I just want to know whether it is valid or not.

Something like:

```
Page.IsValid("MyValidationGroup")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
protected bool IsGroupValid(string sValidationGroup)
{
   foreach (BaseValidator validator in Page.Validators)
   {
      if (validator.ValidationGroup == sValidationGroup)
      {
         bool fValid = validator.IsValid;
         if (fValid)
         {
            validator.Validate();
            fValid = validator.IsValid;
            validator.IsValid = true;
         }
         if (!fValid)
            return false;
      }

   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 You can also use `Page.GetValidators("<your group name>")` which would simplify code a small bit.

Answer (score 38):

Have you tried using the [Page.Validate(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwzxc386.aspx) method?  Based on the documentation, it looks like it may be what you want.

```
Page.Validate("MyValidationGroup");
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    // your code here.
}
```

Note that the validators on the control that also caused the postback will also fire.  Snip from the MSDN article...

> The Validate method validates the
>   specified validation group. After
>   calling the Validate method on a
>   validation group, the IsValid method
>   will return true only if both the
>   specified validation group and the
>   validation group of the control that
>   caused the page to be posted to the
>   server are valid.

Comment: It's worth to mention this will display validation messages on failed validations.

Answer (score 10):

```
var isValidGroup = Page
                    .GetValidators(sValidationGroup)
                    .Cast<IValidator>()
                    .All(x => x.IsValid);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Page.Validate("MyValidationGroup");
if (Page.IsValid) 
{
    //Continue with your logic
}
else
{
    //Display errors, hide controls, etc.
}
```

Not exactly what you want, but hopefully close.

Comment: So will Page.Validate cause my ValidationSummary to display?

Comment: You would need to programmatically disable/hide the validation summary if you want to use this solution in that manner.

Answer (score 3):

Page.IsValid will be false if any of the validated validation groups was invalid. If you want to validate a group and see the status, try:

```
    protected bool IsGroupValid(string sValidationGroup)
    {
        Page.Validate(sValidationGroup);
        foreach (BaseValidator validator in Page.GetValidators(sValidationGroup))
        {
            if (!validator.IsValid)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pavel's answer works but isn't the simplest.  Here is how I solved it:

```
protected Boolean validateGroup(String validationGroupName) {
        Boolean isGroupValid = true;

        foreach (BaseValidator validatorControl in Page.GetValidators(validationGroupName)) {
            validatorControl.Validate();

            if (!validatorControl.IsValid)
                isGroupValid = false;
        }

        if (!isGroupValid)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```