# ASP.Net: RegisterOnSubmitStatement not calling the specified javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Upon failing validation the `BackgroundSize` of these `TextBox`es sets from 0px to 20px. I got this technique from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1197500).

Problem: The code in click event of the button doesn't run the specified javascript.

code-behind:

```
public static _Default d = new _Default();
public static ValidatorCollection signupValidators = d.GetValidators("signupGroup");
protected void btnSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  /***** i put a breakpoint here ******/
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(), "currentValidator", "onUpdateValidators();");
}
```

Javascript:

```
function onUpdateValidators() {
    alert("Alert! In Javascript");
    for (var i = 0; i < signupValidators.length; i++) {
        var currentValidator = signupValidators[i];
        var control = document.getElementById(currentValidator.ControlToValidate);
        if (control != null && control.style != null) {
            if (!currentValidator.isvalid) {
                control.style.backgroundSize = "20px";
                alert("in onUpdateValidators()");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First time ever doing this so no idea what's wrong =(

[EDIT:]
Could there be something wrong with my `Button`?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSignup" runat="server"
                Style="width: 150px; height: 40px; border-radius: 2px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #499234; margin-left: 70px; margin-top: 10px"
                Text="Create New Account"
                CausesValidation="true"
                ValidationGroup="signupGroup"
                PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" <%-- removing this doesn't work either --%>
                OnClick="btnSignup_Click" />
```

Because i put a breakpoint on its click event and the execution doesn't break there

Answer (score 0):

For `Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927446/registeronsubmitstatement-after-client-side-validation)

Else try this:

First Add `AjaxControlToolKit` reference and than from AJAX Extenions in Toolbox add `ScriptManager` in your page after `<form runat="server">`

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        //your other logic

    </form>
 </body>
```

And than in code behind use this:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "onUpdateValidators", "onUpdateValidators();", true);
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer @Just.Programmer and let me know if its not working.